# Determinate State of Linear Congruential Generator from Results

Tags: random

I am curious on how someone would go about determining the state of a Linear Congruential Generator given its output.

```
    X(n-1) = (aX(n) + c) mod p
```

Since the values returned are deterministic and the formula is well known, it should be possible to obtain state's value. What exactly is the best way to do this?

Edit:

I was at work when I posted this and this isn't work related, so I didn't spend much time and should have elaborated (much) further.

Assume this is used to generate non-integer values between 0 and 1, but its only visible output is **true** or **false** with a 50/50 spread. Assume the implementation is also known, so the values of **a**, **c** and **p** are known, but not X.

Would it be possible, with an finite amount of output, to determine the value of X?

Comment: Are you asking programmatically, or mathematically?

Comment: I would like to know both

Comment: You might get more responses on [the math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/), but you could start with [this old discussion](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/LCG) in sci.math.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the simplest case, the output IS the state -- the output is the sequence X<sub>0</sub>, X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, ... each element of which is the internal state at one step.

More commonly, the LCRNG will be divided to generate uniform numbers in the range [0,k) rather than [0,p) (the values output will be *floor*(kX<sub>n</sub>/p),) so will only tell you the upper bits of the internal state.  In this case, each output value will give you a range of possible value for the state at that step.  By correlating multiple consecutive values, you can narrow down the range.